# High Voltage shares ground, Problems?

Tags: voltage, schematics, high-voltage, short-circuit

I am having a problem with identifying why a high voltage part of my circuit broke the low voltage controller. To start, the basic premise of the circuit is to take a very accurate 0-10V DAC voltage(VCTL) and turn it into 0 to 1000V. This was all done for me as I inherited the box of circuits. The schematic is below. There are two sides, +1000V and -1000 V. The problem is that the -1000 V had a short and when the selector(HV_Polarity_rotary) moved it to connect it to the output(HV-1), it was shorted to ground through C21 and R24. There is a DAC board connected at Vctl, and the negative side of that board is shorted because of this(the current going to the negative voltage of that board is 100x higher than all the other voltages). I checked all the paths to that Vctl and nothing is wrong with any of the ICs or resistors or capacitors.

I don't know what broke the DAC boards but could it be the shared ground? My only problem with thinking this is that only the negative side of the DAC boards is broken and I would think all of them would be broken if it was through ground. [Here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad5791.pdf) is the DAC board I am using. The schematic is on page 26. 
[image: Schematic for High Voltage board]

I guess a TL;DR of it would be can a high voltage/current going to ground effect small ICs on that same ground.

Comment: Are there some net names that are off screen? For example, the polarity switch nets don't have a counterpart. None of the nrts containing  "HV" in fact. All dead ends.

Comment: The polarity switch off on the right side just signifies that you choose from (HV-,GRND, HV+) to connect to the HV out which is at the top right

Comment: I'm thinking the drain of U2 was held low (perhaps held at GND thru D2), while the gate was high. Thus the gate-channel oxide was ruptured.

Comment: That could be the case but then I would not know how that causes all my low voltage equipment to get fried.